# Git rebase results in a conflict; git status then shows ALL the local files got modified

Tags: git, rebase

I have a feature branch `featureBranch` that is yet to be merged to `main`. I need to now rebase my feature branch on latest commits from `main` so I do:

```
git log
# commit <commitID-3>
# commit <commitID-2>
# commit <commitID-1>

git status 
# Your branch is up to date with 'origin/featureBranch'

git checkout main
git pull
git checkout featureBranch
git rebase main

# error: could not apply <commitID-1>... initial first commit
hint: Resolve all conflicts manually, mark them as resolved with
hint: "git add/rm <conflicted_files>", then run "git rebase --continue".
hint: You can instead skip this commit: run "git rebase --skip".
Could not apply <commitID-1>... initial first commit


git status
# shows ALL the files that haven't been changed since the latest commit and rather changed across different commits within featureBranch
```

So the rebase failed due to a conflict in a file that needs to be manually resolved HOWEVER upon running `git status` after, I see ALL my files that have been changed/created within `featureBranch`. And they're older revisions too.

Is this expected? If I do `git rebase --continue`, am I committing the older revisions of the files?

Is git rebase supposed to apply the very first commit?!

Comment: Please edit the question to show, not describe, the results of the commands you’ve run. It’s fine to truncate/redact sensitive or repetitive info.

Comment: yessir! done....

Comment: Git status results are still not shown

Comment: what else do you really wanna see in git status? what i showed should indicate

Comment: Is featureBranch an orphan branch? According to your description there is no commit before commitID-1?

Comment: @xyf to confirm they are staged for commit. It’d also be helpful to diff one file. It’d be a much faster process if you didn’t question why missing info is needed :).

Answer (score 1):

First: the most common source of this problem is end-of-line formatting changes.  To avoid that, use `--ignore-cr-at-eol` or similar.  Meanwhile, to answer your final question:

> Is git rebase supposed to apply the very first commit?!

Sometimes, yes.

There are seven or so keys to understanding `git rebase`:

- Commits are essentially snapshots of all files.
- The hash ID of a commit is its true name: Git *needs* the hash ID to *find* the commit.
- A branch name just stores one hash ID.  Whatever hash ID is in that branch name, that's the *last* commit on that branch.
- Every commit records its parent(s), specifically their hash IDs.
- No commit, once made, can ever be changed, so Git doesn't try to do that.
- The `git cherry-pick` command can turn a commit—a snapshot—into changes, by diffing the commit against its parent commit.  This assumes that there is exactly one parent; see below for some special cases.  Having turned a commit into "make these changes to these files", Git can now use those instructions to make the *same* changes to the *same files* in some *other* commit.  Technically this is a full three-way merge, except that Git doesn't save the result as a *merge commit* (with two parents), but rather as a new single-parent commit.  The end result is to *copy* a commit, sort of.
- Since changing commits—including their parentage—is impossible, `git rebase` doesn't do that: instead, it makes a list of commits that, presumably, you mostly like except for their ancestry.  It then checks out some *other* commit and runs a sequence of `git cherry-pick` operations, one per commit, from the list it made earlier.  Then `git rebase` takes the branch name that *found* the commits-to-be-copied and yanks it around so that it now finds the just-copied commits instead.

The end result of all this is just what you'd want, in most cases.  You start with, e.g.:

```
          C--D--E--F   <-- feature (HEAD)
         /
...--A--B--G--H   <-- mainline-or-develop
```

for example, where each uppercase letter stands in for one of the big ugly hash IDs.  You *like* the commits on `feature`, except for one thing: they start out from commit `B`.  You'd like them *more* if they built on commit `H`, like this:

```
          C--D--E--F   [abandoned: old and lousy]
         /
...--A--B--G--H   <-- mainline-or-develop
               \
                C'-D'-E'-F'  <-- feature (HEAD)
```

By listing out the hash IDs of the original `C-D-E-F` commits, then checking out commit `H` and running four `git cherry-pick` operations, and finally yanking the name `feature` around so that it finds commit `F'`—the new and improved copy of what used to be `F`—`git rebase` winds up getting you exactly what you wanted.

But suppose you have this:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- br1 (HEAD)

E--F--G--H   <-- br2
```

Here, there are no parent/child or ancestor/descendant relationships between commits on the "top row" (found via `br1`) and those on the "bottom row" (found via `br2`).  If you run:

```
git rebase br2
```

now, Git will list out each of the four commit hash IDs `A-B-C-D`.  That includes the *root commit* `A`, which has no parent.

Here's where the special case for cherry-pick comes in.  Whenever we have something other than a single parent, cherry-pick needs some help with the idea of turning a commit into a set of changes.  For a *merge* commit, Git needs you to tell Git which parent to treat as "the" parent temporarily.  But for a *root* commit—one with *no* parent—Git can just assume that there's some kind of ur-commit `ε` at the front, that has *no files at all* in it, and diff against the [empty tree](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9765453/1256452).  All files in commit `A`, as compared to empty commit `ε`, are newly added.

This will give you add/add errors on *every file* if commit `H`, onto which commit `A` is being cherry-picked, has the same set of files as commit `A`.  This is not all that unusual: it can happen when someone uses history rewriting tools, for instance.

Note that there are fancier forms of the `git rebase` command to handle some of these issues.  For instance, suppose we'd like to copy *just* commits `C-D` atop `H` in our `br1`-and-`br2` setup.  We can run:

```
git rebase --onto br2 br1~2    # or HEAD~2
```

The `--onto` argument separates out the otherwise-overloaded required argument (which `git rebase` calls the *upstream*, which is perhaps not the best choice of word here) so that it can be used to list the hash ID or other identifier that locates the first (or last, if you read history forwards, instead of backwards) commit *not* to copy.